# Service reference addition issue in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, geocoding, bing-maps

I am currently working on an application that allows reverse geocoding using silverlight + bing maps. The thing is that I want to add a reference to the reverse geocoding service provided in msdn ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879136.aspx) i.e. http:// dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc?wsdl, but when I try to get a reference in vs2010, I get the following error:

The document at the url http:// dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/metadata/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.wsdl was not recognized as a known document type.

The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

- Report from 'XML Schema' is ''', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is ''', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 1).'.

  - '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc?wsdl'.
    Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http: //dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc?wsdl.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
    The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
    If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

It is good to mention that I can access the service URL from the browser (with a no style information warning). I am aware that there are other reverse geolocoding services out there, but I am somewhat forced by certain circumstances to use only Microsoft-related components/services. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried the same thing and it seems to work fine for me. I saw an article on the MSDN newsgroups that suggest there may have been a problem at some stage with the references (see a post on [Bing Map Route Calculation Service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/8363e895-883d-4a2c-844f-f12bc6b96cdb)) although it mentions that it was the staging URL's that were causing a problem, not those that you're using (as in the article currently). Other than that, are you using the current RC of VS2010? (on the off chance that there were issues in an earlier version)

Might be worth trying again; I've whipped up a stub application at http://code.google.com/p/bingmapssilverlightapp/downloads/list if it's any use.

Comment: Well, the strange thing is that i've tried it againd the second day and it worked :) same visual studio (yes, it was the rc), same interet connection, everything. Perhaps it was the reboot...:)